# Issues with docerised mosquitto: Error opening password file

Tags: linux, docker

I am very new to docker and pretty new to linux so please be gentle!

I am trying to get the official docker mosquitto image to work with a password file. My config file:

```
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/

listener 1883
password_file /mosquitto/config/mqtt_passwd
```

my run command:

```
sudo docker run --rm -i -p 1883:1883 -v /volume1/mosquitto:/mosquitto eclipse-mosquitto:latest
```

when it runs:

```
1646914188: mosquitto version 2.0.14 starting
1646914188: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.
1646914188: Error: Unable to open pwfile "/mosquitto/config/mqtt_passwd".
1646914188: Error opening password file "/mosquitto/config/mqtt_passwd".
```

so the config file and the password file are in the same folder with the same permissions:

```
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 1883 1883 114 Mar 10 12:09  mosquitto.conf
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 1883 1883 121 Mar 10 11:14  mqtt_passwd
```

this 1883 user is weird. I think that the docker image changes the permissions when it boots up. within the container the permissions are:

```
----------    1 mosquitt mosquitt        71 Mar 10 12:18 mosquitto.conf                                                       
----------    1 mosquitt mosquitt       121 Mar 10 11:14 mqtt_passwd
```

it's strange to me that it can access the config file but it can't access the password file.

Many thanks for any help

Comment: How are you running the container? Can you share the full command as it may shed some light!

Comment: This is on Synology so it's done through a UI. I'll reverse engineer a run command though and update the post with it

Comment: Have you solved this? I have a similar issue on Azure although I do not use docker.